# how to find if mouse over a button at specific frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

how to find if mouse over a button at specific frame without attaching an event listener 
something like this (code in frame 5):

```
on(button1.MOUSEOVER){
  //do some staff
}
```

or something like this (code in frame 5):

```
button1.MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER = function() {
    //do some staff
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**OK! i found answer** (code in frame 5):

```
trace(button1.hitTestPoint(mouseX, mouseY, false));
```

over button1 return true otherwise return false

```
if (button1.hitTestPoint(mouseX, mouseY, false)) {
   //do some staff
}
```